# Haskell Type errors (short code)

Tags: haskell, types, casting

first I'd like to appreciate your time answering my question.

First, please take a quick look at my code. You don't have to understand the code, just pay attention to the types.

This return an error that says,

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
Expected type: [Int]
  Actual type: [Integer]
In the first argument of `myfun', namely `primes'
In the expression: myfun primes
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

I can run this successfully with no error if I change the types to Int instead of Integer, so for example, "primes :: [Int]"

However, I am required to keep it integer for the program to be able to take large numbers.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: "However, I am required to keep it integer for the program to be able to take large numbers." <- No, you aren't. With that algorithm, you won't wait long enough to generate primes outside `Int` range even with 32-bit `Int`s, that would still take several decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from `(!!)` in `myfun`:

```
myfun (a:ab) = fibs !! (a-1) : myfun(ab)
```

which a newer GHC would have probably informed you about (I think). Try this:

```
myfun (a:ab) = fibs !! ((fromInteger a)-1) : myfun(ab)
```

`fromInteger` is polymorphic in its result type, so here the type system infers you want an `Int`. [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Integer+-%3E+a) knows a lot about these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `myfun` is derived from the type of `!!`, which is `[a] -> Int -> a`. If you're using a number as a list index, you have to make it `Int`, anyways, your numbers are limited by the list capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your type error is that `(!!)` has the type `[a] -> Int -> a`, and as a consequence, `myfun`'s type is deduced as `[Int] -> [Integer]`.

If you truly need `Integer`s, `fromIntegral` won't help you; it will simply cause your application to crash with a negative index once the primes exceed `maxBound`.

However, `(!!)` has poor asymptotical complexity, so the best solution is reworking your algorithm so as not to require quadratic runtime behavior.

For example, instead of traversing the entire list of fibs each pass, you can instead express the primes as a list of index intervals to drop:

```
> import Data.List
> intervals :: [Integer]
> intervals = zipWith (-) (tail primes) primes
```

and collect the results of dropping prime intervals from the fibs:

```
> partC :: [Integer]
> partC = map head $ scanl (flip genericDrop) (tail fibs) intervals
```

I have used `tail fibs` here since you skip the first number in the fibonacci sequence.